# alignment issue with gridlayout

Tags: android

I have a number pad as shown

[image: here]

As you can see, buttons with only single line are not properly aligned. I got to know that by setting `android:baselineAligned` as false we can solve this. But GridLayout does not have any such property.

How can i solve it?

**EDIT:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/buttons_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:columnCount="3" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width=""65dp
                android:layout_height=""40dp
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="1" />

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width=""65dp
                android:layout_height=""40dp
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="2\nABC" />

.
.
.
      </GridLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your code and tell us what you've tried

Comment: Did you finally find any solution?

Comment: Honestly, I do not remember :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem also with a fixed height of the textviews which were children of the appcombat GridLayout. 
The wrong alignment showed up everytime I had a cell with a textview with two lines and not like the others with one.

For me the rows got correctly aligned when I added an

`grid:layout_rowWeight="1"`

Can't explain it, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by wrapping every element with a dummy layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```